# ls colors showing unicode replacement character

Tags: solaris, ls, colors

On Solaris 11.4 when I try to use `ls` with colors in an SSH session, the output is correctly colored but there is a question mark in a box at the end of every line like this.  I tried ssh from both Linux and Windows PC.
This problem does not happen on the local Solaris terminal.

```
$ ls -l --color=auto
total 5453
drwxr-xr-x   2 elliott  staff          3 Aug 27 09:06 aix
-rwxr-xr-x   1 elliott  staff       1168 Aug  6  2012 build_sds.txt
drwxr-xr-x   6 elliott  staff          7 Aug 27 09:06 classes
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Double check if `TERM` is something like 'xterm-color' and if your shell rc was properly loaded.
I used to have issues loading `~/.kshrc` under ssh session.

Comment: TERM is xterm-256color and I'm using bash

Comment: Have you tried xterm-color or just xterm ?